# Have fixed positioned child obtain the same exact width of its parent, when parent's width is declared in percentages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Most of use knows that fixed elements are never relative to their parent, and are instead relative to the port size, and thus setting their width or height to 100% will make it relative not to their parent, but to the port size. There is a way around this, and that is to use the keyword 'inherit' instead in declaring its width, but there's one problem with this:

```css
#wrap1 {
border: 1px solid black;
position: relative;
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#fixed1 {
border: 1px solid red;
position: fixed;
width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'wrap1'>
<div id = 'fixed1'> fixed </div>
</div>
```

^---When the size of the fixed element's parent is declared in pixels, the fixed element matches the size of its parent, however...

```css
#wrap2 {
border: 1px solid black;
position: relative;
width: 50%;
height: 250px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#fixed2 {
border: 1px solid red;
position: fixed;
width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'wrap2'>
<div id = 'fixed2'> fixed </div>
</div>
```

^---You don't see the intended effect here, which is that the child will have exactly half of the parent's width, instead of having the same exactly width of the parent, because the width of it's parent is 50%, instead of in pixels. But when the code is isn't run on SO's code snippet, this is exactly what you will see.

Is there a way for a fixed positioned child to have the same exact width of its parent, when its parent's width is declared in percentages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason here is that an element with a fixed position is relative to the viewport - and percentage width measurements are computed relative to the viewport itself. In your percentage example, the parent's `width: 50%` is computed relative to the `body`, minus the body's 16px margin. Your fixed element inherits `width: 50%` from its parent, but the percentage is computed relative to the entire viewport, which completely wraps around the body and its margin (hence the fixed element extends past its parent).

One solution that can give the fixed element its parent's width, is to remove the margin from the body.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#wrap2 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#fixed2 {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: fixed;
    width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'wrap2'>
<div id = 'fixed2'> fixed </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Please update this statement in your question, which suggests you're looking for half the parent's width: *"^---You don't see the intended effect here, which is that the child will have exactly half of the parent's width"*. I've updated the answer with the exact width.

Comment: While changing the margin here, in this sample example, works just fine. In a complex website, with more than just 1 or 2 elements, that both have their own padding, margins, suddenly it doesn't work as well anymore.

Answer (score 0):

change your #fixed2 CSS style as below.

```
#fixed2 {
border: 1px solid red;
position: inherit;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: This approach will make the element expand to the full size of the viewport.